vscode + wsl + git - specify work-tree and git-dir directories on a per-workspace basis
I am trying to manually configure git-dir and work-tree while running vscode with a remote WSL session, but I want those settings to be specific to one workspace and not carry over to other workspaces. I can set them universally via a shim with git.path, but git.path can't be specified on a per-workspace basis. Another way to do it would be to configure environment variables that only apply to a given workspace, but env seems to be something you specify in launch.json, not in any given workspace's setting.json.
This post suggests setting an environment variable before launching vscode, but I am trying to make this setting specific to a workspace and not have to relaunch vscode in a different environment every time.
Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Can you please give more concrete examples of what you try to achieve ? for example: will your workspaces be something else than git repositories themselves ?

I maintain various configuration files (~/.bashrc etc) as a git bare repo, where git-dir is ~/.cfg. Basically, a variation on the technique described at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles . When editing files like .bashrc in VSC, I'd like it to rely on ~/.cfg as git-dir. But for other projects (e.g. those hosted on github), I would like it to use the traditional .git structure. So I need git-dir to be different, depending on my workspace, and can't figure out any way to manually specify git-dir other than at the level of the entire application, rather than per-workspace.

I would suggest using, as suggested in the article, an wrapper on top of the git command dedicated to your config. In the article, they suggest a bash alias, but you may be in a chicken-and-egg situation if you want to define this alias in your ~/.bashrc. You could instead have a script, which you could copy in your container. Would you have an issue doing that ?

e.g: use dotgit status; dotgit add ...; dotgit commit ...; to handle your dotfiles, git status; git add ... to handle your code.

How do I specify that VSC use the wrapper only in one workspace? I have been able to make VSC always use my wrapper across all workspaces by manipulating either path or git.path, but those settings don't exist on a per-workspace basis. Am I missing something about how you would have the wrapper only apply in a specific workspace? And to clarify: I can certainly interact with my custom git in the terminal, but I am hoping VSC's source code revision GUI hooks into the correct git.

Oh, I think we might be talking past each other: I actually want this for the purpose of editing my dotfiles in VSC. In other words, I want VSC to show the git history of .bashrc when it is open in the VSC editor.

Oh, I see. I don't think vscode's git plugin can support that.

I've figured out a hackish workaround -- I set vscode to invoke my own git shim; that shim looks at pwd to figure out where it is being called from, and then either invokes git with --git-dir forced or not. This seems to work although obviously isn't ideal. If vscode allowed you to set git.path, path, or even just environmental variables, on a per-workspace basis, that would be a better fix.

Do you mean: you invoke that shim from an integrated terminal in vscode ? or do you use vscode's GUI for git ?

$HOME/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json includes the setting "git.path": "vs-git". vs-git is a bash shell script that invokes git based on the pwd: [[ "${PWD}" == $HOME ]] && /usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg --work-tree=$HOME $@ || /usr/bin/git $@
